# Using Partial classes for autogen code, how to setup filenaming etc?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I have a datalayer.cs file that was generated using a code gen tool.

I am marking the class as a partial class, so I can create another file with my own hand written datalayer code.

How should I name my files?

Should I do it like this:

/data/partial/datalayer.cs
/data/datalayer.cs

So when I run my codegenerator again, I just dump the file to the /partial/ folder in my source tree.

suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

VS uses a *Filename.Designer.cs* convention for generated files. You might do something similar. For example, you might have *DataLayer.cs* and *DataLayer.Generated.cs*. I personally would keep the files next to each other in the same directory to aid in discoverability.

Answer (score 1):

Partial classes which are generated by the IDE when you create a Windows.Form are named like:

```
/mydirectory/MyFormName.cs
/mydirectory/MyFormName.Designer.cs
```

So I'd suggest like:

```
/mydirectory/datalayer.cs
/mydirectory/datalayer.autocodegen.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use ClassName_Generated.cs for generated files.  I personally prefer an _ to a . for the generated separator.